# Уточняющий оборот с тире: куда ставить запятую и нужна ли она

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, авторская-пунктуация

Уважаемые участники, прошу вашего совета. Затрудняюсь с постановкой запятой в предложении (после ***этому человеку***):

*Конечно, можно было бы сказать этому человеку, — впрочем, на каком языке? — что имя это носит не только она.*

Правильно ли я ее поставила с учетом, что дальше идут тире и знак вопроса? Может, она вообще не нужна? Автор настаивает на сохранении конструкции предложения.

Само предложение помещено в скобки, поэтому нагромождать еще одни не хотелось бы, чтобы не вышло так: (*Конечно, можно было бы сказать этому человеку (впрочем, на каком языке?), что имя это носит не только она*).

Заранее спасибо всем ответившим.

Comment: Тут без вариантов. Запятая однозначно нужна. И однозначно её не поставить после знака вопроса, хотя логичнее было бы уточняющую конструкцию вставить до запятой, а не после. Но ваш вариант единственный возможный. По сути вопроса: запятая нужна, ставить нужно.

Answer (score 3):

§97 "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации"<sup>1</sup> содержит следующее замечание об использовании сочетания запятой с тире при вставках:

> Употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания следует отличать от сочетания запятой и тире, необходимого по условиям контекста: *Называли фамилии мужей и братьев, — живы ли, здоровы ли они? — как будто этот военный мог знать по именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах.*

То есть, если запятая требуется вне зависимости от вставки, то её ставить нужно. Тут запятая обусловлена самим сложноподчиненным предложением:

*Конечно, можно было бы сказать этому человеку, что имя это носит не только она.*

С вопросительным знаком она сочетаться не может, поэтому сочетается с первым тире, как вы и сделали:

*Конечно, можно было бы сказать этому человеку, — впрочем, на каком языке? — что имя это носит не только она.*

---

1. Валгина Н. С., Еськова Н. А., Иванова О. Е., Кузьмина С. М., Лопатин В. В., Чельцова Л. К. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под редакцией В. В. Лопатина. — 2-е изд., испр. и доп. — М.: Эксмо, 2007.